# nw.js browser showing Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: exec, exe, node-webkit, nw.js

I'm trying to run my exe using nw.js browser. I downloaded nw.js from this link https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js then I created package.json file like this:

```
 {
 "name": "sample",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.html",
 "window": {
 "toolbar": false,
"frame": false,
"resizable": false,
"show": true,
"kiosk": true,
"title": "kiosk example"
 },
"webkit": {
"plugin": true
  },
  "chromium-args": "--ppapi-flash-path=plugins/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=17.0.0.134",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "rohan",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.13.3",
"gulp": "^3.9.0",
"nw-flash-trust": "^0.3.0"
}
}
```

and my index.html is like this

```
<html> 
<head> 

 <script>   

     function RunExe()   
     {   


 var child_process = require('child_process')
, exec = child_process.exec
, execSync = child_process.execSync
, execFile = child_process.execFile
, execFileSync = child_process.execFileSync
;

exec('quiz.exe');

    } 

</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>Run a Program</h1> 
This script launch the file any Exe File<p> 
<button onclick="RunExe()">Run Exe File</button> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I placed my quiz.exe in same folder where nw.exe is present but when my index.html page loads and I click on "run exe file" button nothing happens. I checked console and it is showing this error message: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you code actually works, I've tried it on a clean nw.js v0.12.3 32bit. What is your version of nw.js?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying!! @Vaviloff it works on v0.12.3 32bit.I am going to use this version now..mine was v0.12.3 64bit

Comment: Do you use 64-bit operating system?

Comment: yes,but  if i drag and drop that html file it works but if i access that file through another page it won't work!

Comment: That issue is not related to this `require` question.